# Reading in a .csv file and counting the number of lines between date ranges C#

Tags: c#, csv, readfile

When reading in a CSV file with CSVhelper I have thousands of rows of data, the 5th column of each row will have a date/time in it. I want to count the number of lines between 2 given dates. If we look at the input below:

[image]

The code needs to count the lines between say 2014-10-24 and 2014-10-29 and save this count as a variable, in this case, expected output will be (9). Please note this is a sample input and the actual amount of lines between date ranges will be considerable.

Currently the .csv file is being read in through csvreader and storing in: 
`IEnumerable dataRecord = reader.GetRecords<dataRecord>().ToList();`

I'm stumped as to how to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The class dataRecord is the date a string or a DateTime?

Comment: I think the next step would be to either deserialize each row to a custom type and then use linq to query the result set or to get the date column and use an incrementor in a `foreach` loop

Comment: DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-24");DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-29");int count = dataRecord.Where(x => (DateTime.Parse(x.date) >=startDate) && (DateTime.Parse(x.date) <= endDate)).Count();

Comment: Your code has an error : IEnumerable<dataRecord> dataRecord = reader.GetRecords<dataRecord>().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var count = dataRecord
    .SkipWhile(record => DateTime.Parse(record.Date).Date != new DateTime(2014, 10, 24))
    .TakeWhile(record => DateTime.Parse(record.Date).Date != new DateTime(2014, 10, 29))
    .Count();
```

Comment: @johnfish92 - Use `var` instead of `IEnumerable`.