# How to count occurrences in csv file between two times?

Tags: c#

I was trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821190/reading-in-a-csv-file-and-counting-the-number-of-lines-between-date-ranges-c-sh) solution to count between two times in a csv file.

I tried:

```
var count = _ais.LoadRecords(Parameters.MinDate, Parameters.MaxDate)
        .SkipWhile(record => DateTime.Parse(record.Time).Date != new DateTime(2016, 01, 01,08,00,00))
        .TakeWhile(record => DateTime.Parse(record.Time).Date != new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 09, 00, 00))
        .Count();
```

where `record.Time` is:

```
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

The compiler points at `record.Time` and tells me:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>'
```

Is there a way I can use time here?

Comment: DateTime.Parse expects a string which it should try to convert to a DateTime, but you already have a DateTime. So just use record.Time.Date instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse your record.Time property.

```
var count = _ais.LoadRecords(Parameters.MinDate, Parameters.MaxDate)
        .SkipWhile(record => record.Time.Date != new DateTime(2016, 01, 01,08,00,00))
        .TakeWhile(record => record.Time.Date != new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 09, 00, 00))
        .Count();
```